# Saw a job posting through a recruiter on LinkedIn. How to apply?

Tags: recruitment, united-states, applications, linkedin

I recently came across a job posting on Indeed, and began getting my profile ready on the company's site. Now I just came across a recruiter I have worked with, liking a posting on LinkedIn from the company's recruiter, listing the position as one of several. (At least I think it is the same one.)

Now I am unsure how to proceed; should I contact the corporate recruiter directly, even though I am not directly connected to him? Should I mention it to the recruiter I know? Or should I continue with the company's career page?

My field is Mechanical Engineering, and I am in the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact the recruiter directly and let him/her know that you've applied on LinkedIn as well as Indeed and would think you'd be a good fit for the job.

This way, instead of being scanned by an algorithm you'll have a set of eyes on your resume from someone whom you have a past with and can actively advocate for your candidacy.

Comment: I assume you mean the corporate recruiter (2nd level connection) not the one I am directly connected to?